# How to test for different values and missing keys in multiple dictionaries within a list?

Tags: python

I have a list of dictionaries that represent all of the attributes and values on a selection of nodes in Maya.  I need to find any differences in the values as well as if there are attributes found on some but not all nodes.

`node_dict = [{translateX: 0, translateY: 10, translateZ: 0}, {translateX: 0, translateY: 10, translateZ: 0}, {translateX: 0, translateY: 0, translateZ: 0}]`

I need a way to iterate the list of dicts and return only the keys that are different.  However, if one value is different, then all of those key values need to be returned.

desired output
diff_dict = {translateY: [10, 10, 0]}

My biggest issue is how to setup the for loops or whatever to test each against each other and report out.  Hoping someone has an idea, been hitting this wall too long.

Comment: Please, add more related tags.

Comment: Different how? Are you trying to script to see if all values are zero'd to default? What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: I'm sorry if I didn't give enough info...Given three nodes, I want to compare all three, all of the attributes on said nodes and if any attribute is different, I want the output to have what variable and all three values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just change the representation and check for the condition like this:

```
    node_dict = [{'translateX': 0, 'translateY': 10, 'translateZ': 0}, {'translateX': 0, 'translateY': 10, 'translateZ': 0}, {'translateX': 0, 'translateY': 0, 'translateZ': 0}]
    result = {}
    for x in node_dict:
      for key, value in x.items():
        if key in result:
          result[key].append(value)
        else:
          result[key] = [value]
    
    
    result = { k:v for k,v in result.items() if not (v[1:] == v[:-1]) }
    
    print(result)
```

this will print `{'translateY': [10, 10, 0]}`

The for loop iterate over the dictionaries and reconstruct it to a one dictionary where the keys are the keys on all dictionaries and the values are arrays contains all different values for the same key. The last line check if each list have the same values or not to keep it in the final result.

Comment: Exactly what I needed and was struggling with.  the comprehension, which I need to improve at, was what I expected to solve but just couldn't wrap my head around.  Thanks.